# Matplotlib and PyQt5: spinbox updates the plot, button does not

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I've been trying to integrate PyQt with Matplotlib, mostly using the example code from [here](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/graphics-plotting/plotting-matplotlib/). 
I tried adding some controls to dynamically update the plot. Except, for some reason a QPushButton will not dynamically update the plot while a QSpinBox does. Both of them refer to the same callback function `MainWindow.refresh`.

Here's a minimal working example.

```
import sys
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

import PyQt5.QtWidgets as QtWidgets

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig)

    def redraw(self):
        """
        Draw a line with some noise
        :return:
        """
        self.ax.clear()
        X = np.arange(10)
        Y = X + np.random.rand(10)
        self.ax.plot(X, Y)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        # Make a button. Clicking this does not refresh the plot
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Refresh")
        button.pressed.connect(self.refresh)
        self.hbox.addWidget(button)

        # Make a spin box. Adjusting this updates the plot as intended
        spin_box = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        spin_box.valueChanged.connect(self.refresh)
        self.hbox.addWidget(spin_box)

        self.mpl_canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)

        self.hbox.addWidget(self.mpl_canvas)

        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        central.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        self.show()

    def refresh(self):
        self.mpl_canvas.redraw()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Here's what happens when I run it:

[image: clicking spin box vs clicking button]

How do I get the button to update the plot?

Comment: mmm, it seems to me that it is a Qt bug that affects only MacOS (in Linux I don't see that problem), try adding `self.mpl_canvas.repaint()` after `self.mpl_canvas.redraw()`

Comment: Works fine in Windows 10 as well.

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks! Adding `repaint()` works for me on macOS

Comment: @Heike I can also confirm the code works as-is in Windows. Weird

Comment: It is a known Qt bug in MacOS, in the case that the problem is not observed in the QSpinBox, it is because when changing the value it also changes its size making it repaint, but that size change does not happen in the button.

Comment: @eyllanesc is there a bug report for this yet?